# Como ler/traduzir a palavra-chave yield?

Tags: c#, terminologia, yield

Estou estudando sobre a *palavra-chave* `Yield` em `C#`, e tenho esta dúvida: como ler esta palavra em português (estruturado?). Seria alguma coisa como "retorne o valor atual do enumerador"? Não teria uma tradução de uma só palavra? Se puder dar um exemplo seria bom!

Note que minha pergunta não é exatamente sobre o funcionamento de `Yield`, mas sim de uma boa forma de traduzir a mesma em português.

Comment: "Note que minha pergunta não é exatamente sobre o funcionamento de yield, mas sim de uma boa forma de traduzir a mesma em português." - O site é sobre programação. Há uma proposta de se criar um "Portuguese Language", que será o local adequado para este tipo de pergunta, se a proposta tiver sucesso. Aproveite e participe: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2273

Comment: PS: A dúvida é interessante, só o meio de satisfazê-la não é bem esse. Entretanto, se alguem puser um __comentário__ respondendo a dúvida, mal não fará.

Comment: "Produz". Li esta traducao a alguns anos, e achei bem apropriada.

Comment: @Bacco na verdade minha pergunta so tem sentido no contexto de programação, c#, e língua portuguesa, por isso fiz a pergunta aqui :)

Comment: @ClickOk Entendo o ponto de vista, mas achei por bem comentar. De qualquer forma, se puder ajudar com a proposta do Portuguese Language, resolvemos 2 problemas de uma vez ;)

Comment: @Bacco Me cadastrei na Area51. Boa sorte a nós, lusófonos :)

Comment: E eu aproveitei e também me cadastrei... Estava divulgando, mas eu mesmo esqueci de dar o _commit_ na proposta :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma tradução boa para a palavra `yield` seria **produz**, como dito pelo usuário @OnoSendai nos comentários.

Outras traduções possíveis:

- Entrega;
- Gera;
- Colhe; (por @jean)
- Coleta; (por @jean)

Comment: Produzir é uma boa tradução lembrando que Yeld não seria "produzir" no sentido de "construir", "montar" e sim no sentido de "colher", "coletar"

Comment: Adicionado suas sugestões, com os devidos créditos. :D