# Qual a diferença entre 'yield' e 'return' no PHP?

Tags: php, return, yield

Andei procurando tirar essa dúvida, mas sem sucesso. À primeira vista me pareciam comandos similares ou que seriam a mesma coisa. Após ver algumas explicações, fiquei um pouco confuso e não tirei minha dúvida.

Se eles não são a mesma coisa, gostaria se possível, de um exemplo que pudesse mostrar a utilização de um e do outro só para ficar mais clara a diferença entre eles.

Comment: Yield é usando com generators e está disponível do php5.5 para frente, o return está aí desde sempre usado geralmente em funções algumas vezes fora delas, avulso mesmo ...

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50208/91

Comment: @rray, eu vi essa postagem e até comentei ela na resposta do bigown, mas não obtive nada nela que pudesse me tirar essa dúvida. Pelo menos não enxerguei nada que pudesse diferenciar um do outro.

Comment: Também havia demorado de entender e é uma ótima pergunta. +1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

De acordo com o manual do php.

Simplificando: Um se trata e um retorno de um valor, outro é para criação de um Generator.

## YIELD

> Uma declaração yield se parece muito com um retorno, exceto que em vez de parar a execução da função e retornar, o yield fornece um valor para o código de loop sobre o generator e pausa a execução da função do generator.

Não vou falar aqui sobre Generators, pois essa pergunta o explcia muito bem:

[Quais as vantagens de usar um Generator (yield) no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50208/quais-as-vantagens-de-usar-um-generator-yield-no-php?lq=1)

Mas trocando em miúdos, o Generator é nada mais nada menor que uma forma simplificada de aplicar um Iterator sobre determinada operação.

Então, quando você usa `yield` você está indicando que o valor passado para ele será parte de uma etapa da iteração que se deseja.  Ocorrerá uma "pausa" na iteração e aqueles valores serão retornados em um objeto da classe `Generator`.

O Generator por sua vez implementa uma interface chamada `Iterator` no PHP. Seria bom entender seu uso, pois nesse caso, não seria importante aprender somente a sintaxe do Generator antes de aprender o que é iterator.

Se sabe o que é um `Iterator` então podemos dizer: Quando você chama um objeto `Generator` com `foreach`, você está invocando os métodos na seguinte sequência:

```
foreach (gen() as $key => $value) {

}
```

Equivale a:

```
$gen = gen();

$gen->rewind();

while ($gen->valid()) {
    $key  = $gen->key();
    $value = $gen->current();

   $gen->next();
}
```

## RETURN

O `return`, que traduzindo é "retorno", serve para retornar um valor para uma função. São dois casos diferentes, já que no primeiro caso, o `Generator` é apenas uma "pausa" para o loop que foi proposto lá dentro. Já `return` representa o valor definitivo retornado para aquela chamada da função.

## Posso usar os dois juntos?

Depende da versão do PHP que você está usando. Se estiver utilizando versões anteriores ao PHP 7, você receberá uma exceção ao tentar colocar `return` e `yield` na mesma função.

No PHP 7, você pode fazer isso. Nesse caso, terá que usar o método `Generator::getReturn`.

```
function gen()
{
     yield 1 => 2;
     yield 3 => 4;

    return 5;
}

gen()->getReturn(); // 5
```

## Outras diferenças

O `return` pode ser usado fora de uma função, já o `yield` não pode.

A melhor forma te obter um `generator` através do `yield`, tendo o objeto Generator diretamente numa variável, é apenas com a self invoking function. Porém ela só está disponível para PHP 7.

Exemplo:

```
 $gen = (function ()
 {
    yield "A" => "B";

  })();

 var_dump($gen); // Generator(object);
```

O `yield` pode ser processado de acordo com o número de declarações, já o `return` não. Você só pode até ter mais de um `return` na função, porém quando o primeiro for executado, o restante será ignorado. Já o `yield` não é assim.

```
function hello()
{
    yield "Stack Overlow";
    yield "Mandioca";
    yield "Milho";
}

$gen = hello();
var_dump($gen->current());
$gen->next();
var_dump($gen->current());
```

A saída será:

```
string(13) "Stack Overlow"
string(8) "Mandioca"
```

Comment: Ainda estou completando a resposta (estou ocupado).

Comment: `yield ++$up;` :D

Comment: Muito boa a resposta Wallace! Completa e esclarecedora :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters termina a resposta aí

Comment: 2 anos, nussa kkkkk

Answer (score 9):

A resposta do Wallace Maxters já está boa, só vou dar uma visão um pouco diferente da mesma coisa.

Vejo o `yield` como o gerador/iterador citado. É o responsável por manter estado entre as chamadas da função que o uso. Ele é o responsável por armazenar onde ele parou na execução da função e, portanto de onde deve retomar quando ela voltar a ser executada.

Por acaso ele tem um `return` implícito na sua execução. Então ele, geralmente, é usado em substituição ao `return` puro que é o retorno simples sem guardar estado.

Informações adicionais para quem está chegando aqui com dúvida total sobre o assunto:

- [Qual a utilidade da palavra reservada "yield"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44293/101)
- [Quais as vantagens de usar um "generator" (yield) no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50208/101)
- [Com fazer um iterator/generator no javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91400/101)
- [Yield não retorna dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38910/101)
- [Como ler/traduzir a palavra-chave yield?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53547/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: não sei qual é o motivo, mas no PHP 7 você pode usar os dois.

Answer (score 7):

Um explicação simples é que o return retorna o valor e termina a função, o yield retorna o valor e dá um "pause" na função (Na próxima chamada ele continua logo após o yield).

Na prática uma não é compatível com a outra e elas são usadas de formas diferentes em contextos diferentes. Se vc se interessar, procure sobre funções geradoras ou iteradores. Se não, só use sempre return e ignore o yield.